# Internal representation of Haskell Data.Map

Tags: dictionary, haskell, data-structures

How can I view the internal representation of `Haskell Data.Map`?
Also, what kind of data structure is used to implement it?
Is it essentially a red black tree?
Or some kind of heap min?
Here is a simple example that I am interested in dumping to a text file
(or even better, a `Graphviz dot` representation).

```
module Main( main ) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map

t = Map.fromList([
    (6,"six"),
    (2,"two"),
    (8,"eight"),
    (3,"three"),
    (5,"five")])

main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ Map.lookup 3 t
    putStrLn $ show $ Map.lookup 7 t
```

Comment: You can see the internals of `Map` via the [`Data.Map.Internal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html) module. The underlying structure is a balanced binary tree, but it balances based on size (as opposed to color). This has the added benefit that querying for size is `O(1)` for no extra cost.

Comment: @Alec surely it could store size while balancing on color.

Comment: @WillNess Yeah. It's just nice that the size info can be reused as is. Otherwise you'd need to pack color into your size bits or have an extra field.

Comment: @Alec, the color is likely to be implicit in the structure of the tree to type rather than a separate field. This prevents you from having to pay a whole word for color and also means that the runtime will almost always know the color of a node before inspecting the node itself, which likely helps the CPU's speculative execution. So I think you pretty much *need* another word to support cached sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a textual dump with `showTreeWith`:

```
module Main( main ) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map

t = Map.fromList([
    (6,"six"),
    (2,"two"),
    (8,"eight"),
    (3,"three"),
    (5,"five")])

main = do
    putStrLn $ Map.showTreeWith (\k x -> show (k,x)) True False t
    putStrLn $ show $ Map.lookup 3 t
    putStrLn $ show $ Map.lookup 7 t
```

And here is how it looks:

```
$ ghc main.hs
$ ./main
(6,"six")
+--(3,"three")
|  +--(2,"two")
|  +--(5,"five")
+--(8,"eight")

Just "three"
Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for Haskell's Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map.html):

> The implementation of Map is based on size balanced binary trees (or trees of bounded balance)